# Object Serialization somehow initialise hibernate proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, proxy

I have a list`(List<Employee>)` with name `employees` returned by hibernate `(session.createQuery().list())` for my Domain `employee`. This list's employee elements has proxies for foreign key elements like `department` which are fetched by `employee.getDepartment()`.

But when I do:

```
{
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("d:\\addresss.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
                oos.writeObject(employees);
                oos.close();
                fout.close();


                ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\addresss.ser"));
                List<Employee> retrived=(List<Employee>)ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            }
```

The list I get then ie `retrived` has employee elements fully initialised but actual list `employees` did not have elements fully initialised.

Question, I need to understand what could have happened during serialization or derserialization that `retrieved` list had initialised elements while actual list `employee` did not.

I'm not 100% sure if above serialization does not call getter/setter methods so there is no way proxies are getting initialised.

Note I did not make call to getter on employee to check if it's proxy or initialised as I know calling a getter will initialise proxy. I just check using eclise debug inspect variables.

Also, one more thing I saw in logs(when department is initialized):

```
System.out.println("class:"+((Employee)employees.get(0)).getDepartment().getClass().getSimpleName()); 
//prints: "Department_$$_jvstfcc_41"


  System.out.println("class:"+((Employee)retrived.get(0)).getDepartment().getClass().getSimpleName()); 
//prints: "Department"
```

Some info:
`employee.hbm.xml` contains:

```
<many-to-one
            name="department"
                    column="department_id" 
        >
```

Hibernate version:`4.3.4.Final`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note to self, an object.getClass() returning names like Department_$$_jvstfcc_41 could still be in initialised state. for more info check: object.getHandler().isUninitialized

Comment: Which hibernate version do you use? Can you post your mapping? I did a small test with Hibernate 4.3.10 and @ManyToOne, and the class name is the same both before and after serialization.

Comment: Just did. Your class name was like Class or Class_$$_blabla ?

Comment: Class_$$_jvst875_0 and the same name after deserialization. The same with 4.3.4.Final

Comment: do one thing, serialise it after initialisation. Then you'll see different classnames. to initialise use Hibernate.initialise(obj).

Answer (score 1):

Serialization does not call getters/setters, neither constructors. This is the eclipse debugger which initializes the PersistenceCollection.

Unless you have some custom serialization code, the collection will remain uninitialized.

You can try adding into your code something like

```
System.out.println(Hibernate.isInitialized(retrived.get(0).getDepartments()));
```

It should print `false`.

or close your session before reading and object. Eclipse debugger will show something like `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.` in value column.

Comment: please look at update where deserialization converts proxy class name to real class name.

Comment: Note that there are no departments but department and hence PersistenceCollection is not there, HibernateProxy is there.